# How to put value containing spaces in option tag?

Tags: php, html

I need to assign a string to value in option tag, which contains multiple words.

```
echo "<option value=".$row['code']." ></option>" ;
```

I tried it like this, but only one word appears.

Comment: You have a typo. It should be `echo "<option value='".$row['code']."' ></option>" ;`

Comment: I understand of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML attributes are separated by spaces. To specify a value, which contains spaces you need to enclose it in quotes, either single `'` or double `"`.

```
<option value="some value" anotherAttribute=1></option>
```

Becuase in PHP you have already used double quotes you can use single quotes now to enclose the value of your HTML attribute.

```
echo "<option value='".$row['code']."' ></option>" ;
```

You could also put the value between the tags as the content, if the value and the displayed content is the same.

```
echo "<option>".$row['code']."</option>" ;
```